# How can I change a form submit with a button to something that works with a click?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have the following:

```
<form action="/Account/LogOff"
   id="logoutForm"
   method="post">
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <button>Logout</button>

   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
</form>
```

The form is submitted when I click the button. However I would like to change the button 
to use a fontawesome icon. Meaning I don't want the button at all. Just to have a fontawesome icon that the user can click on.

How can I change it so that the form gets submitted when I click on the icon instead of 
the button?

Comment: Have you tried inserting an img into the button?

Comment: Hi, I'm wanting no button. Just to have the user click on the fontawesome icon for the form to be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of getting this done!

#### Adding background image

To add the background image to the button itself, you can add this CSS property.

Try this:

```
button {
  background-image: url('..url/to/image');
}
```

#### Adding image as the content of the button

Or this one which will add the image in the button instead of the Logout image, try this:

```
<button><img src="url/to/image.png" alt="photo" /></button>
```

#### Submitting the form using the image

Or this one, which is just a simple image, but using JS, you submit the form when the image is clicked, like this:

```
<i onclick="submit()">Text or something</i>
<form id="form" method="post">
   // elements here..
</form>
```

And in the JS, this one:

```
function submit () {
   document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
```

Note the `onclick` method, and the function! :) You will get the form submitted once the user clicks on the `i` and the form with the ID `form` will be submitted!

Comment: But I don't want to see the button and I'm using fontawesome icons and not an image.

Comment: Then just use the third item! :) And submit the form once the icon or the image is clicked! :)

Comment: I'm not using jQuery can I put this inline with the <i> ?

Comment: @SamanthaJ, have a look at the third note..you will get the form submitted once the user clicks on the `i` and the function will execute to submit the form :) Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Logout</button> //It will add user icon before the text
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want a button. I just want to see the icon and have the user click on that.